# Storing JSON Object to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to store JSON Object into a variable and format it into this ex. (JAN_2018, 
FEB_2018, etc.) and the other is ex. (1081136328, 1069248328, etc.)

[image: SCREENSHOT HERE]

MY CODE:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(json).each(function(i,val){
                $.each(val,function(k,v){
                    console.log(k);
                    console.log(v);
                });
            });
```

I want to put the data **(k and v)** to a variable and format it to **variable 1 =(JAN_2018, FEB_2018, etc.) and variable 2 = (1081136328, 1069248328, etc.)**

Comment: How does you JSON data is formatted when you get it? looking the image it appears that is getting each value separated

Comment: when I put **k** into a variable and output it outside $(json).each function i can get only one data how can i get all of the data and format it into these (JAN_2018, FEB_2018, etc.) ?

Comment: you and create array an push into it right ?

Comment: can you try suggestion given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of array and push value into it  and join array

```
var k_val = [];
var v_val = [];
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(json).each(function(i,val){
                $.each(val,function(k,v){
                    k_val.push(k)
                    v_val.push(v)
                    console.log(k);
                    console.log(v);
                });
            });
   var k_values= k_val.join();
   var v_values= v_val.join();
   console.log(k_values);
   console.log(v_values);
```